# How can i convert my dataset which works exactly same as the tff.simulation.datasets.emnist.load_data() dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, image-classification, federated-learning

How can i convert my dataset which works exactly same as the tff.simulation.datasets.emnist.load_data() dataset?

Is there any predefined function that will do the job with my dataset?
I have parkinson drawing dataset from kaggel which have two type of class called "spiral" and "wave". How can i convert this dataset into a dataset that works exactly same as tff.simulation.datasets.emnist.load_data()...which should have similar kind of class names